# webviewでのフェイスブック参照が出来ない

Tags: html, monaca, webview

表題の通りですがwebviewでフェイスブックの参照が出来ません。
以下のような、方法でやっているのですが上手く行きません。
他のページでは上手く行くのですが、フェイスブックはwebviewができないのでしょうか?
確認デバイスはipod,ipadです。
お詳しい方がおりましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

```html
表示できるURL
<iframe src="//f-tpl.com/sample/tpl_081/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

<hr/>

表示できないURL(Facebook)
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: 念の為の確認も含めなのですが、他の上手くいっているページのURLを質問に追記してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: レスポンス頂き有り難うございます！！
以下のようなものは正常に出ます。

<iframe src="http://f-tpl.com/sample/tpl_081/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: httpsだからではなくてですか？
例えば、https://www.google.co.jp も表示できないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: レスポンス頂き有り難うございます！！
httpに変更したのですが、出来なかったです。ついでにヤフー(http://yahoo.co.jp/)も無理でした。

Answer (score 8):

結論から言いますと、https://www.facebook.com/ はFacebook側がiframeでの表示を許可していない為、iframeで表示することは出来ません。

ブラウザの開発者ツールのConsoleをクリアしてから、質問にある<kbd>► Run code snippet</kbd>をクリックすると、下記のエラーが表示されるかと思います。

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

これはレスポンスヘッダの`X-Frame-Options`に`DENY`が設定されており、ページをiframe内に表示できない事を意味します。

- X-Frame-Options
  https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: iframeでは表示できないという事が分かってよかったです。